# How to reduce webpack bundle size , using gulp & webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, bundle

My webpack js bundle is 300kb, with a very small amount of my own code.
How do I reduce this?

I have tried taking out several imports (although I am not using many libraries

My code is available here. https://github.com/gpitot/gulp-template

My Babelrc file: https://github.com/gpitot/gulp-template/blob/master/.babelrc

My webpack config : https://github.com/gpitot/gulp-template/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js

My gulpfile : https://github.com/gpitot/gulp-template/blob/master/gulpfile.babel.js

I expect there to be some bundled code automatically because of pollyfills but not this much.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Webpack also provides `stats` when you provide `--stats` commandline argument. you can redirect the stats to a file and open the file in https://chrisbateman.github.io/webpack-visualizer/ to see what is the contribution of different modules to the final bundle size. I haven't use webpack with gulp, so cant tell exactly how you can access the stats there. Please check the documentation